# Is Economics S.E. the good place to ask questions about European Operational Programs (ERDF, ESF)? Their economical objectives, indicators, etc

Tags: support

I would to ask some general questions, over the time, about European Programs: European Regional Development Fund, European Social Forum.

Questions about their economical objectives, how to interpret their indicators, etc.

Is Economics Stack Exchange the good stack to ask such question (with which tag?) or do you recommend me using another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can ask questions about those programs. They are definitely on topic per se. However, please note that even for subject matter that is on topic there are some rules here.

For example:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

See more details in the [help](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) center.

So you can definitely ask these questions here as long as you don’t ask for people’s opinions or try to start discussion, or as long as your question is reasonably scoped.

It’s also recommended that you do at least some minimum prior search and show that to make your question better recurved by community (questions that can be answered by first result from a simple google search are generally frowned upon).

Tags will depend on what exact program you are asking questions about. For example, questions about European Regional Development program can be tagged with: development, development economics, economic growth, macroeconomics and policy.

Different EU programs touch on different areas of economics. Policy tag will likely apply to all of them. Other tags are context dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I entirely endorse the answer by 1muflon1, and would add the following, based partly on my experience of having a responsibility for EU grant claims in a UK university finance department prior to my retirement in 2015.

Although you refer specifically to economic objectives and indicators, I am wondering what your "etc" might include. For example, EU grant claims are often subject to very complex rules on how an element for overheads should be calculated for inclusion in grant claims. While a question on such rules might in principle be on topic (and so far as I can see no other SE site would be more appropriate), I suspect that the likelihood of any of the site's regular participants having the knowledge to answer it would be rather low (and that includes myself, the knowledge I had having been largely forgotten and probably now out of date).

Furthermore, any advice given here on such matters should be treated as for educational purposes only, and not as a substitute for reference to official published guidance or advice from the appropriate authorities.